# How do I host the same Flutter web app from two different subdomains

Tags: flutter, subdomain, firebase-hosting

I have a flutter web app that is hosted on a domain like https://app.website.com. I would also like to host it on https://chat.website.com. Based on the subdomain, it should take you to a different landing page, but it needs to be the same Flutter application.

Based on my configuration, the different subdomain loads two instances of the app. This is problematic because authentication and other state is not shared between the two.

I would like different subdomains to point to the same instance of a Flutter app. Is this even possible?

Comment: i dont think it is possible. a flutter app is client side application. browser sees it as two different websites. because of that you cannot share browser's localstorage and sessionstorage.